# JavaScript: replace string inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Maybe I'm making a very stupid mistake but here it goes. I want to take `[ 'hr' ]` and turn it into `[ '* * *' ]` So I did this:

```
var hr = jsonml[i]

console.log(hr)
// outputs: [ 'hr' ]
hr.replace(/hr/g, '* * *')
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Object hr has no method 'replace'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `hr` should be of type `String`

Comment: hr[0].replace(/hr/g, '* * *') ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `hr` is `Array`, try this

```
hr[0] = hr[0].replace(/hr/g, '* * *');
```

or

```
hr = hr[0].replace(/hr/g, '* * *');
```

Comment: `replace()` returns the result of the operation, it doesn't change the variable on which you invoke it. So try `hr = [hr[0].replace(...)]`. (Assuming you want to continue having hr being an array)

Answer (score 1):

hr is an array containing one string element. I would do this way:

```
if (hr.length > 0)
    hr[0] = hr[0].replace(/hr/g, '* * *');
```

EDIT:
or maybe

```
for (var i = 0; i < hr.length; i++)
    hr[i] = hr[i].replace(/hr/g, '* * *');
```

if hr may contain more than one element

Answer (score 0):

You can see the typeof of object :

```
alert(typeof hr);
```

you will see thath this object is an array!

use this :

```
for (i = 0; i < hr.length; i++) {
  var result = hr[i].replace(/hr/g, '* * *');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of providing an answer that actually does what OP asks for (no more, no less):

```
hr = [hr[0].replace('hr', '* * *')];
```

No need to use a regular expression when replacing in this case.